# jquery not getting variable value from C# var

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

the jquery work perfectly when I use the snippets in .aspx including this

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

then I wrote following code in my .cs file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var val = from q in db.ques_tbls select q.qTitle;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

after adding this I changed one line in the script in .aspx like this

```
 var availableTags = <%=val%>;
```

I ended up with this error.
.
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'val' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

```
Line 12:       <script type="text/javascript">
Line 13:           $(function () {
Line 14:               var availableTags = <%=val %>;
Line 15:               function split(val) {
Line 16:                   return val.split(/,\s*/);
```

Comment: my goal is to assign "availableTags ="  with CS variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared val a local variable to your Page_Load method

```
   var val = from q in db.ques_tbls select q.qTitle;
```

It must exist at the class level for the aspx page to use it.  Create a member or property to store the value.

Comment: And its scope must be protected or public, since the ASPX page inherits from the code-behind page.

Comment: also, don't forget to add the delimiters around the javascript variable. They are currently missing.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a function in your C# code which returns the title.

```
protected string returnTitle() {
   DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
   var val = from q in db.ques_tbls select q.qTitle;
   db.SubmitChanges();
   return val.ToString();
}
```

and JS..

```
<script>
    var availableTags = "<%= returnTitle() %>";
    console.log(availableTags);
</script>
```

That will return availableTags as a string though, you may way to tweak it to return an array if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks Jamsi your answer is also very helpful